# How to access excel data in front-end application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, excel, frontend

I have an excel with some constant values(these values would be updated quarterly), I need these values to make calculations and display in my front-end application. Currently there are 2 approaches to this problem that have been implemented:

1. to use any third party library and convert required excel data to json and store it in front-end application and then use it.
2. to create a data service that would read excel data and return whenever its called

Both these approaches work well but I am looking for is something more innovative and maintainable.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there is an excel file with key value pairs e.g. marks of students.